# Xcode using CodeIgniter framework loginAPI (SUDDEN CLOSE OF APPLICATION)

Tags: php, ios, swift3, xcode8, codeigniter-3

I created my own login API and here it is.

*Controller/api/Authentication.php*

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// Load the Rest Controller library
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require APPPATH . '/libraries/Format.php';

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

 class Authentication extends REST_Controller {

public function __construct() { 
    parent::__construct();

    // Load the user model
    $this->load->model('user');
}

public function login_post() {
    // Get the post data
    $email = $this->post('email');
    $password = $this->post('password');

    // Validate the post data
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        // Check if any user exists with the given credentials
        $con['returnType'] = 'single';
        $con['conditions'] = array(
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => md5($password),
            'status' => 1
        );
        $user = $this->user->getRows($con);

        if($user){
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'message' => 'User login successful.',
                'data' => $user
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }else{
            // Set the response and exit
            //BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
            $this->response("Wrong email or password.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }else{
        // Set the response and exit
        $this->response("Provide email and password.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

public function registration_post() {
    // Get the post data
    $first_name = strip_tags($this->post('first_name'));
    $last_name = strip_tags($this->post('last_name'));
    $email = strip_tags($this->post('email'));
    $password = $this->post('password');
    $phone = strip_tags($this->post('phone'));

    // Validate the post data
    if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        // Check if the given email already exists
        $con['returnType'] = 'count';
        $con['conditions'] = array(
            'email' => $email,
        );
        $userCount = $this->user->getRows($con);

        if($userCount > 0){
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response("The given email already exists.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }else{
            // Insert user data
            $userData = array(
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => md5($password),
                'phone' => $phone
            );
            $insert = $this->user->insert($userData);

            // Check if the user data is inserted
            if($insert){
                // Set the response and exit
                $this->response([
                    'status' => TRUE,
                    'message' => 'The user has been added successfully.',
                    'data' => $insert
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
            }else{
                // Set the response and exit
                $this->response("Some problems occurred, please try again.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }else{
        // Set the response and exit
        $this->response("Provide complete user info to add.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

public function user_get($id = 0) {
    // Returns all the users data if the id not specified,
    // Otherwise, a single user will be returned.
    $con = $id?array('id' => $id):'';
    $users = $this->user->getRows($con);

    // Check if the user data exists
    if(!empty($users)){
        // Set the response and exit
        //OK (200) being the HTTP response code
        $this->response($users, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
        // Set the response and exit
        //NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
        $this->response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'message' => 'No user was found.'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

public function user_put() {
    $id = $this->put('id');

    // Get the post data
    $first_name = strip_tags($this->put('first_name'));
    $last_name = strip_tags($this->put('last_name'));
    $email = strip_tags($this->put('email'));
    $password = $this->put('password');
    $phone = strip_tags($this->put('phone'));

    // Validate the post data
    if(!empty($id) && (!empty($first_name) || !empty($last_name) || !empty($email) || !empty($password) || !empty($phone))){
        // Update user's account data
        $userData = array();
        if(!empty($first_name)){
            $userData['first_name'] = $first_name;
        }
        if(!empty($last_name)){
            $userData['last_name'] = $last_name;
        }
        if(!empty($email)){
            $userData['email'] = $email;
        }
        if(!empty($password)){
            $userData['password'] = md5($password);
        }
        if(!empty($phone)){
            $userData['phone'] = $phone;
        }
        $update = $this->user->update($userData, $id);

        // Check if the user data is updated
        if($update){
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'message' => 'The user info has been updated successfully.'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }else{
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response("Some problems occurred, please try again.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }else{
        // Set the response and exit
        $this->response("Provide at least one user info to update.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
}
?>
```

and on my

*Models/User.php*

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // Load the database library
    $this->load->database();

    $this->userTbl = 'users';
}

/*
 * Get rows from the users table
 */
function getRows($params = array()){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->userTbl);

    //fetch data by conditions
    if(array_key_exists("conditions",$params)){
        foreach($params['conditions'] as $key => $value){
            $this->db->where($key,$value);
        }
    }

    if(array_key_exists("id",$params)){
        $this->db->where('id',$params['id']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row_array();
    }else{
        //set start and limit
        if(array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
            $this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
        }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
            $this->db->limit($params['limit']);
        }

        if(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && $params['returnType'] == 'count'){
            $result = $this->db->count_all_results();    
        }elseif(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && $params['returnType'] == 'single'){
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->row_array():false;
        }else{
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():false;
        }
    }

    //return fetched data
    return $result;
}

/*
 * Insert user data
 */
public function insert($data){
    //add created and modified date if not exists
    if(!array_key_exists("created", $data)){
        $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
    if(!array_key_exists("modified", $data)){
        $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    //insert user data to users table
    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->userTbl, $data);

    //return the status
    return $insert?$this->db->insert_id():false;
}

/*
 * Update user data
 */
public function update($data, $id){
    //add modified date if not exists
    if(!array_key_exists('modified', $data)){
        $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    //update user data in users table
    $update = $this->db->update($this->userTbl, $data, array('id'=>$id));

    //return the status
    return $update?true:false;
}

/*
 * Delete user data
 */
public function delete($id){
    //update user from users table
    $delete = $this->db->delete('users',array('id'=>$id));
    //return the status
    return $delete?true:false;
}
}
?>
```

Now on my the XCODE I am trying to connect from xcode to the login API then there's no problem actually it successfully can login but my application is closing without any error after submitting my post request.

I'm suspecting it is because of the basic_auth?

[image]

or not

here's my source code on XCODE

```
@IBAction func buttonLogin(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    //getting the username and password
    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "email": usernameTextField.text!,
        "password": passwordTextField.text!,
        "X-API-KEY": "xxxx-2018"
    ]

    //making a post request
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters:parameters).responseJSON{
        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)

        //getting the json value from the server
        if let result = response.result.value{
            let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
            //if there is no error
            if(!(jsonData.value(forKey:"error") as! Bool)){
                //getting the user from response
                //get the user from response
                let user = jsonData.value(forKey: "user") as! NSDictionary
                //getting user values
                let userId = user.value(forKey: "id") as! Int
                let userFirstName = user.value(forKey: "first_name") as! String
                let userLastName = user.value(forKey: "last_name") as! String
                let userEmail = user.value(forKey: "email") as! String
                let userPhone = user.value(forKey: "phone") as! String

                //saving user values to defaults
                self.defaultValues.set(userId, forKey: "userid")
                self.defaultValues.set(userFirstName, forKey: "firstname");
                self.defaultValues.set(userLastName, forKey: "lastname");
                self.defaultValues.set(userEmail, forKey: "useremail")
                self.defaultValues.set(userPhone, forKey: "userphone")

                //switching the screen
                let profileViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion:nil)
            }
            else
            {
                //error message in case of invalud credential
                //self.labelMessage.text = "Invalid username or password"
                self.showToast(message:"Invalid username or password!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED: So I found out that the basic_auth was not the cause of my app closing. I'm guessing again it is my API??

ADD INFORMATION :

[image]

Comment: "X-API-KEY": "xxxx-2018" shoud be send in headers? Just an ideea .. I encounter this with postman...manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        manager.requestSerializer.setValue("something",  forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")

Comment: Actually now my problem is that my app is closing not because of the header

Comment: if debug is this line actually reached?   self.dismiss(animated: false, completion:nil)   If so, put  self.dismiss(animated: false, completion { yourcode here })  and see if it makes difference. I suspect push and dismiss is the faulty part.

Comment: @user3344236 this line of code `if(!(jsonData.value(forKey:"error") as! Bool)){`inside of it I put print and it didn't reach

Comment: post  all response maybe what you expect does not have that value. and you can use breakpoints in code... instead printing everytime.

Comment: actually it can get all the data and has all values . I'll edit my question I'll add a photo take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183178/discussion-between-user3344236-and-boonmingprog).